# Using "adjunction" to refer to the act of taking adjoints of operators

Tags: terminology, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

I have an especially flabby terminology question.

> How acceptable is it, in your opinion,  to use the word "adjunction" to refer to the process of taking adjoints of operators on a Hilbert space?

An example of the kind of usage I'm thinking of might look something like

> Therefore, the map $T \mapsto TS$ is continuous for each $S$, and continuity of left-multiplication follows by adjunction.

I always find myself wanting to write things like this, but only rarely see it used by other people. Is this terminology deprecated for some reason?

Comment: I would also use it!

Comment: It's absolutely etymologically correct, and it does fill something of a lexical gap. Yet I too have only ever seen the phrase "taking adjoints" in the context you have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure why not, right? Who's it going to hurt?

Answer (score 1):

**I’d advise against using it in this context.**  It’s etymologically correct, true; but it’s neither common nor totally transparent, so non-native speakers of English may be confused by it, and even native speakers may do a double-take.  Since there’s a clearer and more usual alternative, “taking adjoints”, you should avoid tripping the reader up with language unnecessarily — help keep their concentration focused on the mathematics itself!

(However, in a different context — Category Theory — *adjunction* is a defined term in its own right, and *by adjunction* is very common in describing proofs.)

Comment: Duly noted. Thanks for your perspective.